# Can a stream contain some fix huffman compressed block and some dynamic huffman compressed blocks

Tags: zlib, compression, huffman-code, adler32

Is it possible to compress a stream with some blocks compressed with static Huffman encoding, and some blocks compressed with dynamic Huffman encoding? If yes, is it decompressible ?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and yes. A stream can contain a mix of all three block types, with the third type being stored.